# How to auto-insert a row above after the row has been edited

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So this is the layout of the data that I currently have.

What I wanted to do was to shift Columns A to D down whenever I added an entry in A2. So essentially, I would always keep a blank top row for columns A to D where the data would be keyed in every time.

[image: File Data]

I've somehow figured out how to insert a full row with this code. However, since it adds a full row, it also moves the entire legend down and I want to keep it where it is.

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("TEST");

  var editedRange = e.range;

  if (editedRange.getA1Notation() === "A2") {

      sheet.insertRowBefore(2);
  }
}
```

How should I change the `insertRowBefore` function? I'm pretty much new to this and all still learning so I appreciate every bit of help.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you don't want to insert a row, you want to insert a certain number of cells. You can use the method `.insertCells(shiftDimension)` of the Range class.
`shiftDimension` can be `COLUMNS` or `ROWS`. `COLUMNS` will shift your cells horizontally and `ROWS` will shift them vertically.

### Sample:

```
// First you will have to select the range where you want to insert the cells:
var range = sheet.getRange("A2:D2");

// Then call the function with Dimension ROWS to shift the cells down
range.insertCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
```

### Reference:

[Range insertCells(shiftDimension)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#insertcellsshiftdimension)

Comment: Please accept the answer to help other people find it.

Answer (score 0):

Pl. organize your data in two tabs (one for data and and the other for the legend).

Add a new row at the bottom to improve speed as shifting the entire data down takes more time.

The Legend data can be displayed in the data sheet by ArrayFormula easily.